# Loop 2 dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want to be able loop this 2 dimensional array and return the size of the first list.

For example:

```
double[][] array= {
        {  15.0, 12.0},
        {  11.0,  16.0},
        { 16.0, 12.0},
        { 11.0, 15.0},
    };
```

I am thinking along the lines of using a loop within a loop structure like....

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < array.length; j++)
        {
            //
        }

    }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure the Q is. Why not just check the first list then? array[0].length

Comment: This is a very very very basic question. Are you sure you could not have found the answer on Google? Or in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner for loop should check the length of the inner array

```
for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            //
        }
}
```

Or use foreach

```
for(double[] row : array) {
  for(double cell : row) {
     // 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of the first dimension you don't need loop , just make this

```
 int len = array.length/// the length of the first list
```

but if you want to get the size of the second dimension ,  and the array not empty so get the length of the first element , like this :

```
 int len = array[0].length// the length of the second one
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to iterate over elements in a 2D array:

```
for(double[] row : array)
{
  for(double element : row)
  {
     // Use element here.
  }
}
```

Its a row wise iteration. So if array is like:

```
double[][] array = {{1.2, 3.4}, {4.5, 5.6}};
```

Then `element` will have 1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6 values in it at each iteration respectively.
Safe, fast, clean and concise.